# Correct way of sending form values to server - React

Tags: reactjs, json, laravel, form-data

I am using react js for front end and to manage form values I ma using Formik. For backend I am using Laravel.

My for includes string value, array value and file. Inside onSubmit function formik gives all my data as object.

Now to receive file data on server I have to convert my data into `FormData()` but the problem is it converts the array values into comma separated string.

To overcome this problem I tried to use `JSON.stringify()` but it sends an empty array on server for file objects. Now to avoid this I tried to use `getFile()` to convert file value into fileObject but that too does not work and gives me error

```
ReferenceError: getFile is not defined
```

*Note: I am using Laravel's form request class so I don't get chance to json_decode the request data. I am sending `Content-Type : 'application/json'` in the request header so laravel json_decodes the request itself*

I want to know what is the best way for sending all kind of form data to the server?

Comment: Do you use axios in the frontend? If yes, maybe you forgot to add this header: 
`headers: { 'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data" }`
because `new FormData().append()` should work.

Comment: I am already receiving file on server using form data but it has problem with array field values